# How to prevent Error List Window from showing up within Visual Studio ASP.NET Editor?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, editor, markup, error-list

Any errors or warnings within the markup pops up the window and it reminds me VB6 error message box, stealing the focus and concentration.

Quite an eyesore.

**Is there a way to prevent the `Error List` window from showing up while editing ASP.NET markups?**

Comment: Can't you just close it or set it to always be minimized?

Comment: @Yuriy: It still pops up.  At least I figured out a keyboard short-cut key to close it (Shift-Esc) but that still isn't good enough.  Since it stills my focus...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least with the other IDE settings (i.e. C#/Windows, not ASP.NET), you can just hide or close the error list and have it pop up on each compile.